# How to efficiently pass a variable from Matlab to GPU in an asynchronous way?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, cuda, streaming, mex

In my CUDA project, I can define a pinned memory, copy the data from a .txt file to the pinned memory and use streaming to copy the data to GPU while doing my processing in a Kernel.
Now, I want to make a CUDA MEX file and then pass my data (called RfData) variable to it in Matlab. However, I have noticed that there is no way of directly allocating arrays coming from MATLAB as a pinned CUDA memory. I have to do it with a pageable memory then:

```
    int* RfData;
    RfData = (int *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]); 
    int* Device_RfData;  
    int ArrayByteSize_RfData = sizeof(int) * (96* 96* 2048);
    cudaMalloc((int**)&Device_RfData, ArrayByteSize_RfData);
    cudaMemcpy(Device_RfData, RfData, ArrayByteSize_RfData, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

I need to copy the RfData async using streaming. The only way I know is by copying the RfData to a pinned memory and then using streaming:

```
     int* RfData_Pinned;
    cudaHostAlloc((void**)&RfData_Pinned, ArrayByteSize_RfData,  cudaHostAllocWriteCombined);
    for (int j = 0; j < (96* 96* 2048); j++)
    {
        RfData_Pinned[j] = RfData[j];
    }
```

However, it increases the overall processing time of my MEX function.

How can I transfer my data from Matlab to GPU in an async way? Maybe there is a command in CUDA that allows a fast copy of data from pageable to pinned memory?

Thanks in advance,
Moein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed allocate pinned memory with `cudaHostAlloc` but if you have already allocated memory, you can instead just pin it with `cudaHostRegister`, that takes an already allocated host array pointer (taken from `mxGetPr` in your case).

Note that this will take time to pin the memory, but possibly less tha doing `cudaHostAlloc` and then copying it.

Comment: Ok. So, if i understood correctly, i need to use:

 cudaHostRegister(RfData, ArrayByteSize_RfData, 
       cudaHostRegisterMapped);

to pin the already defined pageable memory (RfData), which comes from  mxGetPr  in my case. then, I can use RfData pointer as the pointer to a pinned memory to do streaming with. right?

Comment: @MoeinMozaffarzadeh yes. That is correct. I use `cudaHostRegisterPortable` but I can't remember now on top of my head why that and not `cudaHostRegisterMapped`, or if it makes a difference. After, simply use `cudaMemcpyAsync` with the last argument being the stream. I use all this on the TIGRE toolbox in case you want an example, but its likely a bit obfuscated to be an easy example to follow.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Do i also need to free this memory with a specific command or just free(RfData) works fine?

Comment: @Moein you shoudl unpin it. As its a matlab array (you just got the pointer) I believe matlab will free it when it sees fit.